# I want to draw a car in java that moves from side to side but it doesn't really work. Feel free to comment and edit it! Thanks

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

```
 *I want to draw a car in java that moves from side to side but it doesn't really work. Feel 
 free to comment and edit it! I am just trying to use java.awt.event, java.swing, and java.awt! Thanks*
```

I want to draw a car in java that moves from side to side but it doesn't really work. Feel
free to comment and edit it! I am just trying to use java.awt.event, java.swing, and java.awt! Thanks
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
***I am only using these import***

```
   public class Java2D extends JFrame{
   int xValues[];
   int yValues[];
   private JButton Right, Left;

   public Java2D() {
       super( "Drawing lines, rectangles and ovals" );
       setSize( 500, 300 );
    setVisible( true );
}

   public void paint( Graphics g ) {

       int xValues[] = { 40, 100, 130, 230, 260, 320, 320, 40 };
       int yValues[] = { 120, 120, 40, 40, 120, 120, 170, 170 };
       Polygon polygon1 = new Polygon( xValues, yValues, 8 );
      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.drawPolygon( polygon1 );
```

**I am trying to make the car out of polygons**
***Import colors***

***I am also trying to make a background but I will do that later***
**I think using an instance variable might make the car move**

```
    Right = new JButton("Right");
    Left = new JButton("Left");

    Right.setSize(50, 50);
    Left.setSize(50, 50);

    Right.setLocation(100, 200);
    Left.setLocation(200, 200);

    g.add(Right);
    g.add(Left);

   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getActionCommand().equals("Right")){
        for (int i=0; i<xValues.length;i++) {
        xValues[i] = xValues[i] + 10;
        yValues[i] = yValues[i] + 10;
        }
    }

    if(event.getActionCommand().equals("Left")){
        for (int i=0; i<xValues.length;i++) {
        xValues[i] = xValues[i] + 10;
        yValues[i] = yValues[i] + 10;
        }
    }

   repaint();
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Java2D application = new Java2D();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't extend from top level containers like `JFrame`, you're not adding any new functionality and are locking yourself into a single use case.  Also overriding `paint` of a top level container is not recommended (lots of reasons), instead, start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, just don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`, otherwise you'll be in for some trouble.

Comment: See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details

Comment: Also, create your assets out side of the paint workflow, a component can be paint a number times and your just increasing the GC overhead if you create short lived objects in paint all the time

Comment: *"but it doesn't really work"* doesn't really explain what the problem is or what we should be focused on.  A [mcve] will go along way to helping us understand the issue, although, since you're not call `super.paint`, I suspect that's the core issue

Answer (score 1):

Don't extend from top level containers like JFrame, you're not adding any new functionality and are locking yourself into a single use case. Also overriding paint of a top level container is not recommended (lots of reasons), instead, start with a JPanel and override it's paintComponent method, just don't forget to call super.paintComponent, otherwise you'll be in for some trouble.

See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

This example is using an image for the car, but you can replace the `drawCar` workflow with what ever you like.

If you're using a `Polygon` or `Shape` instead, then you will need to translate the position of them (or the `Graphics` context) in order to be able to them.

As a proof of concept example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new MainPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage car;
        private BufferedImage road;

        private int horizontalPosition = 106;

        public MainPane() throws IOException {
            car = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Car.png"));
            road = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Road.png"));

            JButton left = new JButton("<");
            JButton right = new JButton(">");

            JPanel actionPane = new JPanel();
            actionPane.setOpaque(false);
            actionPane.add(left);
            actionPane.add(right);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
            add(actionPane, gbc);

            left.setFocusPainted(false);
            right.setFocusPainted(false);

            left.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int halfCarWidth = (car.getWidth() / 2);
                    horizontalPosition -= halfCarWidth;
                    if (horizontalPosition - halfCarWidth < 0) {
                        horizontalPosition = halfCarWidth;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            right.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int halfCarWidth = (car.getWidth() / 2);
                    horizontalPosition += halfCarWidth;
                    if (horizontalPosition + halfCarWidth > getWidth()) {
                        horizontalPosition = getWidth() - halfCarWidth;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(213, 216);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            drawRoadSurface(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            drawCar(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void drawCar(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            int x = horizontalPosition - (car.getWidth() / 2);
            int y = (getHeight() - car.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.translate(x, y);
            g2d.drawImage(car, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void drawRoadSurface(Graphics2D g2d) {
            int x = (getWidth() - road.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - road.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(road, x, y, this);
        }

    }
}
```